# Cor de uma aplicação Android

Tags: android, xml

Eu estou tentando deixar a cor do aplicativo como Branco (por padrão), mas não consigo fazê-lo...
Isso é possível? Ou terei que definir a cor elemento por elemento?

Não consigo também mudar a cor da ActionBar, segue o código relevante:

```
<style name="Theme.David" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle.David</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_david</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.David</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.David</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.David</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.David</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.David</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_david</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_david</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.David</item>

    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_david</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.David</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.David</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.David</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.David</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.David</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_david</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_david</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.David</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.David" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle.David</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_david</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_david</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_david</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.David</item>

    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_david</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_david</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_david</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.David</item>
</style>

<style name="TitleTextStyle.David" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Porque não usa o tema `Theme.AppCompat.Light` apenas? Se não for isso, crie o diretório `res/values-14` e defina o `ActionBar.Solid.David` com `android:background` e os demais atributos com o mesmo prefixo.

Comment: Excluí o "DarkActionBar" e também incluí os itens com o prefixo "android:", mas a cor do texto e da ActionBar continuam pretos... Não entendo o que pode estar acontecendo :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você usa um style que usa o `AppCompat` precisa **também** colocar todos os atributos com `android:`como prefixo, por exemplo:

```
<style name="ActionBar.Solid.David" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle.David</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle.David</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_david</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_david</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_david</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_david</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_david</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_david</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.David</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.David</item>
</style>
```

Detalhe: se você está utilizando o minSdk como 11 você não precisa usar o `AppCompat` nos seus styles. Neste caso, você poderia deixar apenas os atributos com o prefixo `android:` na frente, removendo os que não possuem, por exemplo:

```
<style name="ActionBar.Solid.David" parent="@style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle.David</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_david</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_david</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_david</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.David</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Eu adicionei os itens que não tinham o prefixo "android:", (meu minSkdVersion é o 11) mas ao tentar remover o "AppCompat" e trocá-lo por "Holo" o AndroidStudio não reconheceu...

Comment: @Mukotoshi testou da primeira maneira que mencionei?

Comment: Sim, eu atualizei o código atual... (Tem mais coisas no código, que foi gerado pelo http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/)

Comment: @Mukotoshi você colocou sua activity com este tema no seu AndroidManifest?

Comment: Sim:
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.David" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.PrincipalActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

Comment: @Mukotoshi você extendeu sua activity para `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity` ?

Comment: Na verdade eu extendi para FragmentActivity, porque utilizo FragmentTabHost com TabWidgets

Comment: @Mukotoshi herde para `ActionBarActivity`e teste

Comment: As cores continuam pretas, não entendo o que pode estar acontecendo...

Comment: Eu não estava atualizando minha "styles" na pastas "values-v14", depois que a atualizei o código funcionou. Você saberia me dizer se preciso utilizar essa pasta ou se posso excluí-la? (essa pasta foi gerada automaticamente)

Comment: @Mukotoshi se você quiser fazer algo específico para a api 14 pra cima, você precisa deixar esta pasta sim. Caso contrário, não

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado. Vou excluí-la, se eu precisar crio novamente depois.